# Waiting for Sidekiq's result and then show it to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I've just implemented a very basic Sidekiq's task (fetching data using a GET request) and since this needs to be done in my root_path in order to populate the database, I'm wondering if there's something I can do in order to refresh the page or something so the users don't notice it?

```
def index
    @q = Jobs.ransack(params[:q])
    if params_from_search_empty(@q)
      @pagy, @jobs = pagy(Jobs.all, items: Jobs::NUM_JOBS_TO_FETCH)
      FetchJobs.perform_later if @jobs.empty? || @pagy.count.empty?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      # Search results
      @jobs = @q.result(distinct: true)
      @pagy, @jobs = pagy(@jobs, items: Jobs::NUM_JOBS_TO_FETCH)
    end
  end
```

As you can see, `FetchJobs.perform_later` will do its job but until the database is populated with its results, the user will be redirected to the root_path and they won't see anything until they reload the webpage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is user expectation, depending on your use case just letting the user know that it's been enqueued for later processing might be all you need to do. They won't be alarmed that it's not showing up, and they'll refresh on their own to see when it's done.

In some use cases it might make more sense to send them an email or text message. And in still others you might want to push the notification to them in the web UI using ActionCable.

Comment: thanks @smathy, I'll check `ActionCable` out!